# Disable atomic transaction in Django 1.11 change view

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-admin, django-1.11

Django 1.11 has following piece of code

```
@csrf_protect_m
def changeform_view(self, request, object_id=None, form_url='', extra_context=None):
    with transaction.atomic(using=router.db_for_write(self.model)):
        return self._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
```

in

```
env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py
```

As per [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/transactions/#why-django-uses-autocommit) Django 1.11 is supposed to be working in auto commit mode but the changeform_view does not seem to be aligned to the documentation. Django admin form save is happening within a transaction.

I solved by overriding the method in ModelAdmin class of the model.

```
def changeform_view(self, request, object_id=None, form_url='', extra_context=None):
    return self._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
```

But is there a way to enable autocommit mode for django form for all the models with a setting ?

Comment: Running in auto-commit mode may not always lead to inconsistent state. In our usecase, that is not a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've misunderstood [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/transactions/#django-s-default-transaction-behavior).

> Django's default behavior is to run in autocommit mode.

"Default behavior" here means "behavior in the absence of specific guidance on the scope of the transaction". In the `changeform_view` you cited, the code is explicitly using the transaction API, indicating that it does not want to use the default autocommit mode.

Note that your change will not ensure that the code runs in autocommit mode. That's because any of the functions called from within `_changeform_view` might themselves use the transaction API, thus disabling autocommit. Many pieces of Django use transactions because they're essential to ensuring correct behavior.

So there's no setting or other method to disable the transaction API across all of Django.